# Posicionar div dentro de elemento hijo, pero fijo a la pantalla

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo divs de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El div verde es un elemento hijo, dentro tiene el div blanco.

El div blanco debe estar centrado dentro dentro del verde, hasta ahí va bien, pero necesito que el div blanco quede fijo con respecto a la pantalla, no con respecto al div verde.

Para que se centre bien, en el div verde estoy usando la propiedad

```css
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Cabe mencionar que el div azul no es de tamaño fijo, y si quito esa propiedad, el div blanco se queda fijo de forma correcta con respecto a la pantalla, pero no se centra bien con respecto al div verde.

Agradecería me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: "Cabe mencionar que el div azul no es de tamaño fijo", ¿a qué div azul te refieres?

Comment: Al que se encuentra a la izquierda, yo lo veía azul, aunque tal vez sea un tono de gris

Comment: Entiendo. Copia el código para ayudarte mejor